# Find minimum (where $0<x,\:y,\:z<1$), $\sqrt{x^2+y^2-2y+2}+\sqrt{x^2+z^2-2x+2}+\sqrt{y^2+z^2-2z+2}$

Tags: inequality

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem:

Q: Find minimum (where $0<x,\:y,\:z<1$)
$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2-2y+2}+\sqrt{x^2+z^2-2x+2}+\sqrt{y^2+z^2-2z+2}$$

My work: Just as an expression with two roots can be interpreted as a distance in a plane,
$$(x,1,0),\:(0,y,1),\:(1,0,z)$$
the above expression is interpreted as a distance in space to find a value that minimizes the sum of the distances, but it does not work. Please let me know how to solve it algebraically or geometrically. thank you

Comment: Notice the symmetry of the problem.  Also, for any $~0 < k < 1,~$ the expression $~k^2 + (1-k)^2~$ is minimized at $~k = \dfrac{1}{2}.~$  This should **informally** suggest an optimum value for each variable $~x,y,z.~$  Then, you would have to **prove** that this informal suggestion is optimal.

Comment: You can still use the Minkowski's inequality to turn this into a single-variable optimization problem which nicely happens to be minimized at the unique triplet the aforementioned Minkowski's application is also an equality. 

Geometrically, this might have a cute solution by some extra constructions of the cube on the some of its faces, like the geometric solution for [Fermat point](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Generalization/fermat_point.shtml)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality, we have:

$$\sqrt {x^2+(1-y)^2+1^2}\sqrt {(\frac{1}{2})^2+(\frac{1}{2})^2+1^2}\geq \frac{x}{2}+\frac{1-y}{2}+1 \\ \implies \sqrt {x^2+(1-y)^2+1^2} \geq \sqrt {\frac{2}{3}}(\frac{1-y+x}{2}+1).$$

Similarly,

$$\sqrt {z^2+(1-x)^2+1^2} \geq \sqrt {\frac{2}{3}}(\frac{1-x+z}{2}+1), \\ \sqrt {y^2+(1-z)^2+1^2} \geq \sqrt {\frac{2}{3}}(\frac{1-z+y}{2}+1).$$

Therefore,

$$\sqrt {x^2+(1-y)^2+1^2}+\sqrt {z^2+(1-x)^2+1^2}+\sqrt {y^2+(1-z)^2+1^2} \geq \\\sqrt {\frac{2}{3}}(\frac{3}{2}+3)=3\sqrt {\frac{3}{2}}. $$

The equality happens at $x=y=z=\frac{1}{2}$.